# Problema al compilar (Java)

Tags: java, compilar

Tengo un problema con este código de java

estaba siguiendo un curso y me resultaron raros los errores que me tiraban al compilar

Luego copie el código del profesor a la perfección y sigue tirando el error.

¿Acaso java actualizó su sintaxis?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cadena{
  public static void main(String args[]){

  String cadena_original = "", cadena_substraccion = "";
  int num_caracteres = 0, desde = 0, hasta = 0;
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Introduce una cadena de caracteres: ");
  cadena_original = in.nextLine();

  num_caracteres = cadena_original.length();

  System.out.println("La cadena de caracteres " + cadena_original + " pose " + 
                      num_caracteres + " caracteres.");

  System.out.print("¿Desde que caracter desdeas obtener la nueva cadena?: ");
  desde = in.nextInt();
  System.out.print("¿Hasta que caracter desdeas obtener la nueva cadena?: ");
  hasta = in.nextInt();

  cadena_substraccion = cadena_original.substring(desde, hasta);
  System.out.println("La nueva cadena es: " + cadena_substraccion);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo acabo de probar y no me da ningún error, lo único que en el código que has introducido si el archivo está dentro de un paquete te faltaría: "***package nombrepaquete***;" al inicio del código y ojo con el "***public class Cadena{***  " ya que donde dice Cadena tiene que llamarse igual que tu archivo. A mi me pasaba al inicio que copiaba códigos me daba errores y era por esas tonterías. Un saludo!

Por cierto, si usas NetBeans pulsa: CTRL+ALT+F y se ordena el asunto y así es más fácil de leer. Con otros entornos de desarrollo ni idea pero tienen que tener algo :P.

Comment: Creo que el compilador fue el problema , ahora lo probé en eclipse y si funciono

Comment: Gracias por responder !